# Angular 4 Compatible WYSIWUG Editor

Tags: angular, wysiwyg

I am building an app that has a WYSIWYG component to it, and i have been looking at the tons of jQuery based ones out there. I haven't found one that has the following things as well as a decent wrapper in NG2.

- Support to attach files from local (I am aware I will need to write some behind the scenes upload process)
- Code Snippet Insert
- Source View (seeing the RAW Html)
- embed ability (like Gists from Git or other things like that

If this is the wrong place to ask, I appreciate being pointed to the right place to ask.

Comment: There is list with some awesome ng2+ editors https://libraries.io/explore/typescript-ng2-libraries?keywords=wysiwyg